# Unreal Engine5 LiveCoding causes error `(missing LinkerPath field)`

Tags: c++, json, unreal-engine5, livecoding

[image: the error message]

I'm a new to unreal engine5. I made a blue print project, and added a c++ file, but when compiled, It causes the error, **unable to parse C:/program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.1/Engine/Intermediate/LiveCoding.json (missing LinkerPath field)** as the above. so, I added the **LinkerPath** field to **"C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Intermediate\LiveCoding.json"** like this:

```json
{
    // the `LinkerPath` field is added, the others not changed.
    "LinkerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\link.exe", 

    "LinkerEnvironment": {
        "LOCALAPPDATA": "C:\\Users\\우수컴\\AppData\\Local",
        "OneDrive": "C:\\Users\\우수컴\\OneDrive",
        "UE_DesktopUnrealProcess": "1",
        "ProgramFiles(x86)": "C:\\Program Files (x86)",
        "__COMPAT_LAYER": "ElevateCreateProcess",
        "PROMPT": "$P$G",
        "PUBLIC": "C:\\Users\\Public",
        "SystemRoot": "C:\\WINDOWS",
        "SESSIONNAME": "Console",
        "SystemDrive": "C:",
        "USERNAME": "우수컴",
        "CommonProgramFiles": "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files",
        "DriverData": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData",
        "USERPROFILE": "C:\\Users\\우수컴",
        "COMPUTERNAME": "DESKTOP-OBEKLM1",
        "OPENSSL_ia32cap": ":~0x20000000",
        "CommonProgramFiles(x86)": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files",
        "PROCESSOR_LEVEL": "6",
        "NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS": "24",
        "CommonProgramW6432": "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files",
        "LPP_PROCESS_RESTART_ID": "37608",
        "APPDATA": "C:\\Users\\우수컴\\AppData\\Roaming",
        "TEMP": "C:\\Users\\우수컴\\AppData\\Local\\Temp",
        "USERDOMAIN": "DESKTOP-OBEKLM1",
        "windir": "C:\\WINDOWS",
        "HOMEPATH": "\\Users\\우수컴",
        "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE": "AMD64",
        "HOMEDRIVE": "C:",
        "ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN": "1",
        "Path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.22000.0\\x64;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX64\\x64;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\\bin;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\;C:\\Users\\우수컴\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\우수컴\\.dotnet\\tools;C:\\Users\\우수컴\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin",
        "VC_COMPILER_PATH": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe",
        "PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER": "Intel64 Family 6 Model 183 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel",
        "PATHEXT": ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC",
        "ProgramFiles": "C:\\Program Files",
        "OS": "Windows_NT",
        "LOGONSERVER": "\\\\DESKTOP-OBEKLM1",
        "FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING": "Internet Explorer",
        "ComSpec": "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",
        "PROCESSOR_REVISION": "b701",
        "UBTPath": "\"..\\..\\Engine\\Binaries\\DotNET\\UnrealBuildTool\\UnrealBuildTool.dll\"",
        "ProgramW6432": "C:\\Program Files",
        "ALLUSERSPROFILE": "C:\\ProgramData",
        "PSModulePath": "C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules",
        "USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE": "DESKTOP-OBEKLM1",
        "VC_COMPILER_DIR": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX64\\x64",
        "FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING": "Default",
        "ProgramData": "C:\\ProgramData",
        "EOS_OVERLAY_ENABLE_VULKAN_WIN64": "1",
        "TMP": "C:\\Users\\우수컴\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
    },
    "Modules": [
    ]
}
```

But the result is same. How do I solve this error?.

Comment: Try looking this link: https://community.gamedev.tv/t/visualstudio-code-error-unable-to-build-while-live-coding-is-active/203606

Answer (score 1):

This actually worked for me:

Delete your .vs, intermediate, and binaries folders with UE and VS closed.  Then  regenerate your visual studio project files.